# How can I extend the div azure square to fill the square, brown in color?

Tags: html, css

1 - How can I extend the azure  square `<div id="Blue">` to fill the square, brown in color?

2 - How can I match the `#frame` size height to my resolution window becose is some time bigger and then Sliding window to scroll down to see the bottom and some time it smaller?

Thx for any help

You can see here  [Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/hfuGx/43/show/)

Relevant Code.

**Html**

```
<div id="frame">
    <div id="inside_window">
        <div id="Yellow"></div>
        <div id="Green"></div>
    <div id="Blue"><img src="http://www.centerwow.com/stackoverflow/shark.png"  height="50" width="50" />
    <img src="http://www.centerwow.com/stackoverflow/ship.png"  height="100" width="120" /></div>
    <div id="Red"></div>
    <div id="ver"></div>
    <div id="hor"></div>
    <div id="ver2"></div>
</div>
```

**Style**

```
#Blue{
    position: absolute;
    min-height:100%;
    min-width:75%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;    
    margin: 0 150px;    
    background-color: #62A9FF;
    z-index:10;
    display:table;
    font-size:220%;
    cursor: url(http://www.centerwow.com/stackoverflow/magnet.png), auto;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
}
```

Comment: change min-height to height:100%;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here goes the answer for your first problem: http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/hfuGx/49/

**change min-height to height:100%;**

```
#Blue
{
    position: absolute;
    height:100%;
    min-width:75%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;    
    margin: 0 150px;
    background-color: #62A9FF;
    z-index:10;
    display:table;
    font-size:220%;
    cursor: url(http://www.centerwow.com/stackoverflow/magnet.png), auto;
    left:0px;
    top:0px; 
}
```

**For your second question:**
add below given css on the top of your css code:

```
html, body{height:100%;}
```

**Note:** If the browser window height is too small it will show a scroll bar, because it will take the height as sum of green & red div.